Error message “User has already voted this way. Undo the vote, or change the vote to continue” when undoing certain actions
There seems to be a bug where unfollowing posts, unaccepting an answer, and retracting (un)deletion votes gives this message:


User has already voted this way. Undo the vote, or change the vote to continue

This occurs on posts throughout the network and leaves the aforementioned actions unchanged, except that one can unaccept an answer if another one is accepted. Additionally, a moderator has confirmed the error message appears here too in chat.
What is the reason and the fix for it?

copy on MSO: Cannot turn off following and get weird message popup

I have a suspicion of what is broken here. Probably once a vote is casted, it's inserted in a sql-table with some unique index. If insert failed, then the vote was already here and the user is trying not to cast another vote but to remove the old vote, and apparently recently some part of the code was messed up and now system believes that user is casting a duplicate vote when they're actually revoking their older vote. (I'm thinking this way because unique index in table is actually one of the ways to implement vote casting/retracting)

(why tho the comment limit is still 600 characters... seems like not enough) anyway in case of such an implementation, an insert error is part of regular vote processing and not an actual error that should be shown to end user

@nicael It's not about voting (that's just the message), it's the result of unfollowing a post, whether directly from question or from your profile page. Might be more broken, since I'm apparently following things yet I've never used that feature.

@Dan yes but follow may still be a vote internally, and as for following things that you never followed, I believe that is because, if I recall correctly, the current "follow" feature was migrated from old "starring/favoriting" feature and you may have used latter in past

@nicael It could have been a misclick, but there's no reason I would have tracked an off-topic question about something I never intended to do with software I don't use. (Also it appeared in the last day or two at most)

@nicael nope, the favorite which later became bookmark is now known as "Saves" and was migrated. The "follow" is different than those and unrelated. (See this for more details.)

@sha ah... this is what happens when you skip 6-8 years and then trying to participate :D

@nicael another change is that bugs without [tag:status-review] aren't going to be fixed, because they're below SE radar, aka don't exist as far as the developers aware. So looks like this bug is going to be around for a very long time. (Developers are not monitoring the sites on their own, and the CM group is most likely busy these days fighting the fires started by SE killing the data dump.)

@DanMašek the web API endpoint for unfollowing is /posts/<post-id>/vote/21 in the path (all the other votes in the Votes table have a similar API endpoint- just a different number at the end). Unfollowing adds ?undo=true. follow info isn't in SEDE, but I bet if it were, it'd have VoteTypeId of 21.

Ouch. This one's a big one, huh?
I woke up this morning and saw a round of bug reports around retracting votes. I could track the issue down to a faulty change we had pushed out to production last Friday. This change touched our vote validation logic, a very central piece of our Q&A code, and it looks like we introduced a bug that went by unnoticed.
Not going to sugar-coat it: We really should've caught this one before getting it out to production, and we didn't. The fact that this bug persisted over the weekend makes this even more jarring. I'm sorry that this happened and apologize that we didn't catch it in time. I'll make sure we look into what happened here and come up with ways to do better next time.
The issue should be resolved now.

I'm really curious what made you push a change in Friday. Change means possible bugs. Why not waiting until today where you can be available after pushing it?

@ShadowWizard we deploy changes to production on every working day. Most of them go out just fine, a few don't. This one was particularly annoying I admit. I strongly believe that "no deploy Fridays" set up software engineering teams with a negative feedback loop. If you aren't equipped to deploy to prod on a Friday, you should work hard to get to that stage by investing in your deployment pipeline and engineering practices, instead of deploying less frequently. Bugs like this demonstrate that we're not where we'd like to be, but they're a great moment to reflect, learn and improve.

I'm curious: what was the exact meaning of the error message, and in what cases is it ordinarily supposed to show up?

Fixed, tnx. I unfollowed all my followed posts.

Negative feedback is generally a good thing -- it helps you keep things under control. Generally this "no release before weekend/holiday" is about respecting your users. If you know you won't be able to attend to potential issues, wait a few days with the release. In most cases the world won't end, but you'll avoid squandering the last bits of trust you have. Especially when you know well enough you're not ready for it (I mean this is a kind of a running gag by now).
